# Get into wheel group

Tags: linux, fedora, sudo

I've kicked myself out of the wheel group by running `usermod -G` without `-a` (add). Now, if I change to root by `su` and do `usermod -aG wheel myuser` I get no output, as expected. Likewise, `groups myuser` outputs: "myuser : myuser wheel ...".
However, after relogging as myuser and just typing `groups` gives me all other groups, but wheel!

1. I googled a lot now and found, that wheel is the `admin` group of some systems. Which? Is fedora such a sys?
2. How do I get the sudo rights back for my fedora user?

the sudoers file has (albeit others) the entries: `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` and the same with `%wheel`

To be more precise: I found a million commands adding users to various groups etc, but none worked for me. Since i do not understand the fact, that I do `#su -c "usermod -aG wheel myuser"` and logged in to my user I still get no wheel group after typing `groups`, I do not know how these things work or what is going on!

and Yeah, `grep wheel /etc/group` gives `wheel:x:10:myuser`

Comment: Not sure if you're using graphical interface. But keep in mind that all group changes are applied only after logout and login (or in completely new session). Closing / opening terminal window in existing X session doesn't work.

Comment: As `root`, what does `groups myuser` show?  It's not absolutely clear from your writeup that you have logged out and in as `myuser` after you added `myuser` back to `wheel`.

Answer (score 2):

Try rebooting.  It looks like you're definitely in the wheel group.  It's likely that you're just not fully logging out; shutting down will remove any doubt that you have logged out.

Answer (score 0):

you can also doing it with the following command:
 `gpasswd -a <username> wheel`
you should received something like: Adding user  to group wheel

To see the user groups you can use: `groups <username> ; getent passwd <username>`

Comment: `getent group <name>` shows the group with name `<name>`, not the groups that a user called `<name>` belongs to.  To see which groups a user belongs to, use `groups <name>` instead.

Comment: No needs to vote Negatively my answer ... just trying to help here